# Did the Spider-man arcade game give Submariner abilities he doesn't have in the comics?

Tags: marvel, video-games, spider-man

In the Spider-Man arcade game made and released in the early 90's, players have the option of playing a character called Prince Namor, also known as Submariner (basically either Marvel's counter to DC's Aquaman or the other way around).

In the game Namor can, as a special attack, shoot what looks like lightning from either his hands or bands on his wrists (it's kind of hard to tell), but I haven't found him doing this in any other depictions of him- does he only have this particular ability in the video game?

Comment: It doesn't matter, because that game was awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. [Namor has had the ability to shoot electricity "like the electric eel"](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/gen-discussion-1/namor-s-electricity-ability-f-y-i-1482942/) for about sixty years.

[image: Captain America blocking Namor's electrical blast]

[image: Namor zapping Doctor Doom]

[image: Namor name-checking the ability being obscure against The Human Torch]

[image: The editors making fun of how the ability is obscure]

[image: Namor expositing on his power being like that of an electric eel]

[This site](https://www.looper.com/172143/the-untold-truth-of-namor-the-sub-mariner/) claims the first showing was in *Fantastic Four #6*, the aforementioned assault on Doctor Doom.

Sadly, I see no mention of the game using his power to [swell up like a puffer fish](https://www.cbr.com/namor-fantastic-four-expand-like-puffer-fish/). No doubt that was being held out for the sequel.

Comment: ...yeah..."ALL the creatures of the sea" opens up some interesting possibilites. Hopefully he's never been frightened like an octopus

Comment: @NKCampbell It could explain why Sue took so long to decide to drop Namor as a boyfriend...